# PHP code works in script but not inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress, xpath

This code works in my PHP script

```
$className = 'mission-dates';
$testQuery = $xpath->query("//*[@class='$className']");
echo $testQuery[0]->textContent;
```

But it doesnt work with a function

```
$test = returnTextFromClass('mission-dates');
echo $test;

function returnTextFromClass($className)
{
$testQuery = $xpath->query("//*[@class='$className']");
$testQuery = iterator_to_array($testQuery);
return $testQuery[0]->textContent;
}
```

When I run it through the function it crashes with critical error (wordpress). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you also post the error message, but looking at your code, the `$xpath` variable is undefined in the scope of your function - meaning the function does not know what `$xpath` is. So I assume an error like `Calling query on null` or `unknown variable $xpath`.

If you defined the `$xpath` outside the method, you need to pass it to the function using `use`:

```
function returnTextFromClass($className) use ($xpath) {
   $testQuery = $xpath->query("//*[@class='$className']");
   $testQuery = iterator_to_array($testQuery);
   return $testQuery[0]->textContent;
}
```

Otherwise you can define `$xpath` as global variable and then access it in your method using `global $xpath`.

If you are in an object-environment, bind the $xpath initialization to to `$this->xpath = ...` and then use it the same way within your method.